# How can I set the Liquibase database connection timeout and retry count?

Tags: timeout, liquibase, connection-timeout

1. How can I set the time that [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) waits to establish a
   connection to a database server (specifically, PostgreSQL) before
   failing (i.e. the connection timeout)?
2. How can I set the number of times that Liquibase will attempt to
   connect to a database server before aborting (i.e. the connection retry count)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liquibase uses a jdbc connection. 
According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18824038/332248) network timeout was only introduced to JDBC from spec 4.1 on.

According to [postgres jdbc doc](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) there is a property like `loginTimeout` that should handle this.

Liquibase will hand over jdbc driver properties to the connection by specifying the command-line param `driverPropertiesFile`.

Haven't tried it myself but it looks good enough to give it a try...

Comment: Oh, as for the retries: I don't see anything in liquibase that would do this. Could be done by a datasource but that seems to be available only in Spring Liquibase or in a CDI context. So maybe there is no way to do this in liquibase...(maybe create a feature ticket in liquibase jira to add this in the future?)

Comment: Spring Liquibase?

Comment: I found http://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/liquibase/integration/spring/SpringLiquibase.html. Is this part of the Spring Integration project?

Comment: Yep. https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/integration/spring/SpringLiquibase.java