# Does liquibase 3.5.x have a default timeout while executing the changeset?

Tags: oracle12c, liquibase, ojdbc

I am new to liquibase and is needed to know whether liquibase 3.5.x using oracle 12 c and ojdbc7 have a default timeout when executing any changeset. I have tried executing very delayed changesets which execute up to 24 hours and liquibase still doesn't timeout even if the changeset is 24 hour delayed. Is there a default timeout when liquibase changeset expires?
If yes, I would like to change the default value to custom defined value.
I have all the source code for liquibase 3.5.x downloaded from https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/tree/3.5.x. 
I have already seen the post explaining an explicit way of defining the jdbc timeout [How can I set the Liquibase database connection timeout and retry count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534122/how-can-i-set-the-liquibase-database-connection-timeout-and-retry-count). But I am looking into something relating to default timeout in liquibase.
      If there is a default timeout defined in liquibase source code, please guide me where can I find it and customize the timeout according to my requirement. 
In the source code, I can see some "timeout"s defined in the postgresql files but cannot find any for the oracle. Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: I think (might be wrong) that there is no statement timeout functionality in liquibase. Liquibase relies on a JDBC Connection to the DB. And the JDBC Connection resp. the JDBC Driver is the one that can define a statement timeout. So I guess you will have to set this on your DB Connection settings for the JDBC Connection.

Comment: Could you please give me an example for it? I don't want to change my application DB connection properties, Can I somehow write a timeout separately, in a properties file or something and invoke this timeout using the -D variable in that specified host which I am executing liquibase? All I wanted to do is to isolate the timeout concept without touching the main application DB connection properties (only exclusive to the specified host) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a simple solution to the above mentioned question.

**For Oracle JDBC connection:**

Liquibase comes with many parameters and one of them is --***driverPropertiesFile=/path/to/file.properties***, where we can specify the required jdbc parameters and link that properties file to the liquibase update command. An example file.properties can have ***oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=6000 (time in milliseconds)***.

 - It is required to "***liquibase releaseLocks***" after a timeout.