# How to set a timeout for liquibase changesets?

Tags: deployment, liquibase

As the title says: how can I set a timeout for liquibase changesets? I need this to ensure that an oversight in a changeset cannot suddenly bring the production environment to a halt.

Comment: What timeout do you want to specify? To limit max duration of changeset execution?

Answer (score 0):

You can set  timeout at jdbc-driver level using property (for example, see [Setting Network Timeout for JDBC connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822552/setting-network-timeout-for-jdbc-connection)) and pass it using -D variable or with property-file to liquibase.