# how to maintain connection for procedures that run for minutes

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee

we are dealing with big data sets which take minutes to execute the stored procedures in the back end ( say 20 minutes).
how to model services to handle these kind of scenarios.

- Synchronous services are ruled out as it will timeout
- Batch processing is ruled out as it will hamper user experience

Is there any framework in java stack to handle this.

Comment: "hamper user experience", but it takes 20 mins? You're having a laugh. You HAVE to use batch processing. A 20 min wait _IS_ a hampered user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Executor Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

It allows multiple threads to be started and waited for, while you can continue doing other stuff.

You can create a connection in a `Runnable` and just maintain that connection until you are done.

Combine it with [network timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10655717/461499).

Comment: there is nothing do after invoking, we just need to invoke stored procedure and wait idle for response .

Comment: Then what is the problem? If you just want to prevent time-outs on your connections, increase the time-out settings. See for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18822552/461499